# Showing packages excluded by yum priorities plugin

Tags: yum

When using the priorities plugin for yum, I get shown the number of packages which have been excluded.  Is there a way of displaying the names of those packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always run yum like this:

```
yum -d 9 install foo
```

and part of the logging output is excluded packages.

**EDIT**

Here's the command I use to see only the excluded packages:

```
yum -d 9 install foo | grep excluded
```

Just in case you were wondering.

Comment: I didn't think of that as a workaround. Have you confirmed this works with the yum-plugin-priorities package installed?

Comment: Yes, I use it all the time to check if a package is being excluded. The only downside is that it produces a lot of output and not all of it is related to the priorities plugin. You may want to run it as "yum -d 9 install foo | grep excluded".

Comment: This is a great workaround then, hopefully if the OP comes back he will see this. Thanks for the information root.ctrlc!

Comment: This works for me too. Using `-d 3` is enough and seems minimally faster.

Comment: Well I'm glad it helped and now I too know to use -d 3. I never bothered to figure out the exact levels, I just cranked it all the way up haha :).

Answer (score 1):

From the docs available via [Fedora's site](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Software_Management_Guide/ch06s14.html), as well as the [CentOS docs](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities) that sort of functionality is not supported.

Comment: I couldn't find this mentioned explicitly on the pages given, but it does seem that there is no simple way of identifying the packages excluded.